# How to fix curl_error: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'api.telegram.org'

Tags: telegram, php-telegram-bot

I am using `telegram.php` to connect my bot. When I use `sendmessage` all of thing is ok in my logs but I do not receive anything from the bot.

When I check my log there is a problem like this:

```
ok:         False
curl_error_code:        51
curl_error:     SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'api.telegram.org'
```

I donit know what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this telegram bot, but I see that it uses **GuzzleHttp**.
During the initialization it doesn't accept any configuration `Request::initialize()`

```
public static function initialize(Telegram $telegram)
{
    if (!($telegram instanceof Telegram)) {
        throw new TelegramException('Invalid Telegram pointer!');
    }
    self::$telegram = $telegram;
    self::setClient(new Client(['base_uri' => self::$api_base_uri]));
}
```

you should check its documentation. I see that there are a lot of setters which makes you able to overwrite the default settings.

What you need is to set the the `\GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::VERIFY` to `false` in the client config:

```
$this->client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri'                          => 'someAccessPoint',
    \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::HEADERS => [
        'User-Agent' => 'some-special-agent',
    ],
    'defaults'                          => [
        \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 5,
        \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::ALLOW_REDIRECTS => true,
    ],
    \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::VERIFY  => false,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**For fix this problem copy this Url to browser and set webhook:**

```
https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/setWebhook?url=https://yourwebsite.com
```

---

Solution 2 of The Error
Let’s follow these simple steps:

Download this bundle of root certificates: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
Put in any location of your server.
Open php.ini and add this line:

```
curl.cainfo = "[the_location]\cacert.pem"
```

Restart your webserver.
That’s it.

Answer (score 0):

just put the line in curl request code
curl_setopt($userid_ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);